# Restore backups automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to automatically restore backups that I stocked in a folder, but when I tried to put the path of the backup, I can't concatenate 'folder path' which is constant and 'backup name'.

Could you help me please

```
CREATE TABLE #myList 
(
     [FileNumber] INT IDENTITY, 
     [FileName] VARCHAR(256)
)

USE Master
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced option' ,1
reconfigure with override

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1
reconfigure with override

DECLARE @SQLCommand VARCHAR(4000)
DELETE #myList WHERE FileName IS NULL

SET @SQLCommand = LEFT ('dir "' + 'Z:\TestBackup' + '" /A-D /B '  , 4000 ) 
INSERT #myList(FileName)
EXECUTE xp_cmdshell @SQLCommand

DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE  CursName CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [FileName]
    FROM #myList

OPEN CursName

FETCH NEXT FROM CursName INTO @fileName

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
     RESTORE DATABASE [fileName]
     FROM DISK = 'Z:\TestBackup\' + @fileName +'' --I have a red line under the symbol +

     FETCH NEXT FROM CursName INTO @fileName
END

CLOSE CursName
DEALLOCATE CursName

DROP TABLE #myList
GO
```

Restore automatically a number of backups

Comment: Personally I think you'd be better off using PowerShell for a task likes this.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu on PowerShell being the right tool for the job. You can get rid of the syntax error by assigning the backup path to a variable for the restore: `DECLARE @BackupPath nvarchar(255) = 'Z:\TestBackup\' + @fileName; RESTORE DATABASE [fileName] FROM @BackupPath;`. However, your script has other errors so I suggest you abandon it and go the PowerShell route as that will be less code and more robust.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Can you possibly show me  the other errors on my script because I need results, And could you tell me please why is PowerShell a better tool? Thank you!

Comment: WIth the dbatools powershell module, you get the Restore-DbaDatabase which you can point at a folder of backups and have it do the restore for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)